# Firefox - Edit and Resend format?

Tags: api, firefox, post, devtools

I have data like this:

```
data={
   "ParamOne":"someval",
   "ParamTwo":10,
   "ParamTree":0
}
```

Using Firefox Network tool *Edit and Resend* I am being able to send POST request to php written API. Now I am trying to send request from client like axios, but without any luck, even using the Postman. How to format send data? Notice that everything must be like in code part. `data` with `=` and `{...}` without white spaces.